# C# Call resources by method

Tags: c#, methods, bitmap, resources

I have the following method that collects the image through resource:

```
public static Bitmap imagem(string pasta, string imagem)
{
    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    pasta = asm.GetName().Name + ".Properties.Resources";
    var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(pasta, asm);
    return (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(imagem);
}
```

How can I call this method in the following code?

```
using (Image<Bgr, byte> Img2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imagem("castelo", "sinal.jpg")) 
{
...
}
```

**I'm getting the error:**

*The name "Imagem" does not exist in the current context*

Please, help me?

Comment: The function is out of scope, possibly declared in another class. Use it's full path (namespace.class.function).

Comment: The parameter `string pasta` is not even used in the method. It is thrown away whatever was in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `imagem` method is static so to call it outside declaring type you need to use type name also:

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public static Bitmap imagem(string pasta, string imagem)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Now to call this method:

```
var result = SomeClass.imagem("someValue", "someValue"); // class name is used here
```

Comment: Thx, i had tried but I had some silly mistake, I redid it and it worked, thanks. Please, can you help me with this other question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488594/c-sharp-click-and-drag-or-mouse-wheel-with-postmessage-sendmessage